# How to stop people from viewing my HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, private

I want to send a link to a client with some work I am doing for them but they are rather informed about IT and that would lead me to think that they know how to copy and paste some HTML and CSS. How would I go about stopping them from seeing the HTML, CSS and JS of the page I want to send them?

Comment: You can't. Consider sending them an image instead.

Comment: send them a pdf or screenshot, but really, you should trust clients.

Comment: Html And CSS are Browser-based Languages! And Clients Can See Codes in Browser `Developer tools` Real,You can Execute it into .exe file , Search in Google For `Html To .exe` For Find Software's For it

Comment: If you want your code secure and on a browser. I suggest you get one of the creative commons licenses(or a more restrictive one) and they would not be able to copy and paste it. Also, minify the code and try to use odd and VERY particular variable and ID, Class names so that IF they do copy it and use it commercially they wont be able to say that they happened to write it themselves.If they know what they are doing, they can obviously change variable names.For all general purposes, HTML, CSS, JS are not languages to strictly hide for viewers. All you can do is make it a pain to steal your code

Comment: For example: view-source:https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not effectively done. While it is true that HTML and CSS can be minified there are a large number of free utilities out there that are designed to reverse the minification, or "beautify", whatever you have minified.

There are a range of other methods which are used on occasion but don't really do anything to protect the source from anyone except those who wouldn't care about the source anyway.

### Source Code Padding

This is one of the oldest tricks in the book and involves adding a ton of white space before the start of the source so that when the user opens the view source window it appears blank, however almost everyone these days will notice the scroll bars and scroll down the page until they hit the source. This also has the extra negative effect of degrading performance for your site as it substantially increases the amount of data being sent to the client.

### No Right Click Scripts

These sorts of scripts prevent the user from right clicking on the page and opening up the page context menu however they are notoriously hard to get working across browsers, annoy users who don't like the native functionality and usability of their browser being altered without permission, and don't make any difference as the source code window can be opened from the top menu.

### Javascript "Encryption"

This is a very popular method to suposedly "protect" the source code of the page and involves taking the code and using a custom made function to encrypt the script before pasting it into the html file and then embedding javascript in that file to decrypt the markup at run time. This only works if the end user has javascript enabled and is not effective in protecting the page from other designers and coders as you need to embed decryption javascript in your page which the user can use to reverse your markup and see the plain text markup.

### HTML Protection Software

There is software out there which is marketed as protecting HTML and CSS however these protection software packages generally use one of the above methods, and charge you for the privilege of having a false belief your code is actually safe.

Unfortunately the way the internet is designed to work with HTML and CSS this is not possible and won't be without such a drastic shift in the web landscape and the way websites are designed that I personally don't see it ever occuring.

---

Information sourced from http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is that they'll steal your work, then maybe you shouldn't be working with them.

Also, if you have a good contract in place that specifies who owns the work at which stage of the process, this won't be an issue. In other words, if it's clear that you own the work until it's paid in full, you could sue them if they steal it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it won't stop people stealing your code, you can make it harder to do so using [minification](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) - this will remove whitespace and translate variables to harder-to-read names, amongst other things. This will also reduce the footprint of your code, icnreasing the page load speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything except obfuscate and minify it.  There are several utilities to do this if you google it.